# How to evaluate $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{\ln{\left(1+e^x\right)}}{x}$ without using L'Hôpital's rule?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

The given limit is from an exercise from the book *Differential and Integral Calculus* by Piskunov:

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{\ln{\left(1+e^x\right)}}{x}$$

The answer in the book is $1$ as $x \to +\infty$ but $0$ as $x \to -\infty$.

Comment: What have you tried and where did you stuck?

Comment: @user I got stuck immediately. I can take the x in the denominator to the exponent inside ln but then what?

Comment: At least the case $x\to-\infty$ should not be complicated, should it?

Comment: Various solutions here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1005495/42969 and here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2583136/42969.

Comment: For large x we have exp(x) >>1, so your fraction is reduced to x/x, which tends to 1

Answer (score 3):

The case $x\rightarrow-\infty$ is easy: $e^x\rightarrow0$, so $\ln(1+e^x)\rightarrow\ln(1+0)=0$ and $\frac{1}{x}\rightarrow0$

For $x\rightarrow+\infty$, notice that $$\ln (1+e^x)=\ln (1+e^x)+x-x=\ln (1+e^x)-\ln e^x+x=\ln\left(\frac{1+e^x}{e^x}\right)+x =\ln (e^{-x}+1)+x$$
Notice that $\ln (e^{-x}+1)\rightarrow0$, so $\cdots$, can you continue from here?

Answer (score 0):

Well $x=\ln e^x$ so
\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{\ln{\left(1+e^x\right)}}{x} &= \lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{\ln{\left(1+e^x\right)}}{\ln e^{x}}\\
&= \lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{\ln e^x{\left(1+e^{-x}\right)}}{\ln e^x}\\
& =\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\left(\dfrac{\ln {\left(1+e^{-x}\right)}}{\ln e^x}+1\right)\\
&\ldots
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$z:=e^x$, and cosider $\lim z \rightarrow \infty.$

$\dfrac{\log (z(1+1/z))} {\log z} =$

$1+\dfrac{\log (1+1/z)}{\log z};$

Take the limit.

Used: $\log (ab) =\log a +\log b$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{\ln \left( 1+e^x \right)}{x}&=\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{\ln \left[ e^x\left( 1+e^{-x} \right) \right]}{x}
\\
&=1+\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{\ln \left( 1+e^{-x} \right)}{x}
\\
&=1+\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{x}
\\
&=1+\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{1}{xe^x}
\\
&=1
\end{align*}
$$

$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} \frac{\ln \left( 1+e^x \right)}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} \frac{e^x}{x}=0
\end{align*}
$$